# Access a session value

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

Here is the Print_r of a $_SESSION variable. I am trying to access the value of user_id.

```
Array ( 

[userPieUser] => loggedInUser Object ( 

    [email] => xxxxx@hotmail.com 
    [hash_pw] => xxxxxxxxx
    [user_id] => 3 
    [clean_username] => scott 
    [display_username] => scott
    [remember_me] => [remember_me_sessid] =>     c13348e6d296b8d96797eed631b20ad13f58e60af00760620327b019e4773c2d6

)
```

)

I have tried a dozen or so ways to get that value in PHP, however no luck. such as looping through and doing `if ($key = 'user_id'){ echo $value }` but that just returns the first element in the array. I'm sure it is rudimentary, however appreciate the help.

Comment: It's `$_SESSION['userPieUser']->user_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you're looking for is:

```
$_SESSION['userPieUser']->user_id
```

As it is part of the `userPieUser` object.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
echo $_SESSION['userPieUser']->user_id;
```

fyi: There is object withing array 'userPieUser'.

Answer (score 0):

Access the variable like so:

```
echo $_SESSION['userPieUser']['user_id'];
```

PHP supports accessing object indicies like this within other object indicies.

Comment: There is an object in array, not array in array.